# Compare keys from 2 objects and replace

Tags: javascript, object, properties, underscore.js

I have 2 objects, one contains the data I want, but I'm also getting some unwanted API names, I have a second object which has the correct names with which to replace the these API names.

But I'm having a hard time swapping them out, I'm unsure how to compare the object keys and swap them out.

```
obj1 = {
        Id: 'XXX123CCCVVV',
        API_NAME__c : 'Joe',
        API_ADDRESS__c : '123 FAKE STREET',
        API_DOB__c : '6/6/1966',
        Account : 'Johnson & Smith',
        Position : 'CEO' 
    }

obj2 = {
        API_NAME__c : 'Name',
        API_ADDRESS__c : 'Address',
        API_DOB__c : 'Date of birth'
    }
```

I would like to compare the keys of these 2 objects, and anywhere they match, swap the value of obj2 for the key of obj1, so obj1 would end up as follows:

```
obj1 = {
        Id: 'XXX123CCCVVV',
        Name : 'Joe',
        Address : '123 FAKE STREET',
        Date of birth : '6/6/1966',
        Account : 'Johnson & Smith',
        Position : 'CEO' 
    }
```

Can anyone suggest a way to accomplish this?

I'm using underscore.js at the moment if that could be of assistance.

---

**UPDATE**

I really appreciate the excellent answers below, but I wonder would it be at all possible to extend this logic to produce a third object containing only the values with the new property names?

So that I'd end up with the following:

```
obj1 = {
        Id: 'XXX123CCCVVV',
        Account : 'Johnson & Smith',
        Position : 'CEO' 
    }

obj3 = {
        Name : 'Joe',
        Address : '123 FAKE STREET',
        Date of birth : '6/6/1966',
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting problem, you can loop the keys of `obj1`, if `obj2` contains that key, replace the key in `obj1` with that value in `obj2`:

```
for (let key in obj1) {
    if (obj2.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        obj1[obj2[key]] = obj1[key]
        delete obj1[key]; //remove old entry
    }
}
```

Or with `.reduce`

```
let newObj = Object.keys(obj1).reduce((o, k) => {
    let newKey = obj2.hasOwnProperty(k) ? obj2[k] : k;
    o[newKey] = obj1[k];

    return o;
}, {});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/f3vuoppf/2/

Comment: Really appreciate the answer, especially the use of .reduce. I've had to edit my question above, I wonder would you be able to extend you answer??

Answer (score 2):

Well simply loop over the keys in `obj2` and update `obj1` if the iterated `key` exists on it with the values from `obj2` and remove the old `value` of this `key`:

```
Object.keys(obj2).forEach(function(key){
    if(obj1[key]){
        obj1[obj2[key]] = obj1[key];
        delete obj1[key];
    }
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
var obj1 = {
  Id: 'XXX123CCCVVV',
  API_NAME__c: 'Joe',
  API_ADDRESS__c: '123 FAKE STREET',
  API_DOB__c: '6/6/1966',
  Account: 'Johnson & Smith',
  Position: 'CEO'
}

var obj2 = {
  API_NAME__c: 'Name',
  API_ADDRESS__c: 'Address',
  API_DOB__c: 'Date of birth'
}

Object.keys(obj2).forEach(function(key){
    if(obj1[key]){
        obj1[obj2[key]] = obj1[key];
        delete obj1[key];
    }
});
console.log(obj1);
```

Comment: interesting, that this answer got an upvote, despite the wrong result.

Comment: @NinaScholz My bad, I misread the question, Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate the keys and replace the properties.

```js
var obj1 = { Id: 'XXX123CCCVVV', API_NAME__c: 'Joe', API_ADDRESS__c: '123 FAKE STREET', API_DOB__c: '6/6/1966', Account: 'Johnson & Smith', Position: 'CEO' },
    obj2 = { API_NAME__c: 'Name', API_ADDRESS__c: 'Address', API_DOB__c: 'Date of birth' };
  
Object.keys(obj2).forEach(function (k) {
    obj1[obj2[k]] = obj1[k];
    delete obj1[k];
});

console.log(obj1);
```

As an alternative, you could generate a new object.

```js
var obj1 = { Id: 'XXX123CCCVVV', API_NAME__c: 'Joe', API_ADDRESS__c: '123 FAKE STREET', API_DOB__c: '6/6/1966', Account: 'Johnson & Smith', Position: 'CEO' },
    obj2 = { API_NAME__c: 'Name', API_ADDRESS__c: 'Address', API_DOB__c: 'Date of birth' },
    obj3 = Object.assign(...Object.keys(obj1).map(k => ({ [obj2[k] || k]: obj1[k] })));

console.log(obj3);
```

The third object ...

```js
var obj1 = { Id: 'XXX123CCCVVV', API_NAME__c: 'Joe', API_ADDRESS__c: '123 FAKE STREET', API_DOB__c: '6/6/1966', Account: 'Johnson & Smith', Position: 'CEO' },
    obj2 = { API_NAME__c: 'Name', API_ADDRESS__c: 'Address', API_DOB__c: 'Date of birth' },
    obj3 = {};

Object.keys(obj1).forEach(function (k) {
    if (k in obj2) {
        obj3[obj2[k]] = obj1[k];
        delete obj1[k];
    }
});

console.log(obj1);
console.log(obj3);
```

Comment: Hey Nina, thanks for you answer! I updated my question slightly, I wonder could you give it a quick look?

Comment: Thanks a lot Nina!